# Крон скрипт, внутри него свое регулирование времени

Tags: php, cron

Есть крон скрипт, который выполняется раз в 10 минут, менять время нельзя.
В этом скрипте несколько задач, но есть одно задание, которые при истинном условии нужно выполнить один раз за сутки. Т.е. условие подходит, выполняем метод и до начала следующих суток этот метод уже трогать нельзя.. Есть возможность реализации этой задумки без сохранения даты в базу или файл?

Вариант:

```
if (date('H') == 12 && date('i') < 10) {// выполняем}
```

Только так?

Comment: чем вас не устраивает такой вариант?

Comment: В принципе нормальный, просто, вдруг без моего ведома время крон-скрипта поменяют на 5 минут или минуту, тогда и метод будет выполняться не совсем адекватно

Comment: `без сохранения даты` - не сохранив состояния не получится однозначно гарантировать, что сегодня скрипт уже был выполнен..

Comment: сервер к примеру в ребут уйдет, когда надо было выполняться. и задача вообще не выполненной останется. если надо гарантировано выполнять раз в сутки, то придется сохранять время, да